# Using non repeating number value from array for label placement

Tags: objective-c

Updated

I'm trying to draw a random number and not repeat the previous number

```
NSArray *placement = @[@300,@400,@500,@600,@700];
float placement1 = [placement[arc4random_uniform(5)]floatValue];
float recentdraw;

if (placement1 == recentdraw) {

//float placement1 = [placement[arc4random_uniform(5)]floatValue];


}

else {

    placement1  recentdraw;
    // den vertikale placering af labelen randomizes nu ved hvert swipe
    self.Label.frame = CGRectMake(30, placement1, 400, 500);
    placement1 = recentdraw;

};
```

what I want to do here is under the 'if' part to set the code to repeat itself. I'm very new in coding, so I hope to avoid creating my own method/function - basically just make this as simple as possible

Couldn't find any thread that made me understand this

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with my question, since no answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[placement[1] floatValue]`. It will return float value of your NSNumber. `@400` is the same as `[NSNumber numberWithInt:400]` and as `CGRectMake` takes only `CGFloat`'s as parameters you need to convert `NSNumber` from the array to the float.